# Converting a dictionary to a List<Customer>

Tags: c#

I have a `dictionary<String,Object>` and I want to convert it to a `List<Customer>`
Is there a clever way of doing that?
Any examples?
Thanks

**EDITED**

Sorry for not explaining properly.
Given the following why is it my result is 0?
Please note I m trying to emulate a live situation and the first key does not make sense and would like to exclude so only customers i should get.
Why does it not work? Thanks for any suggestions

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Customer> oldCustomerList = new List<Customer>
        {
            new Customer {Name = "Jo1", Surname = "Bloggs1"},
            new Customer {Name = "Jo2", Surname = "Bloggs2"},
            new Customer {Name = "Jo3", Surname = "Bloggs3"}
        };
        Dictionary<string,object>mydictionaryList=new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {"SillyKey", "Silly Value"},
            {"CustomerKey", oldCustomerList}
        };
        List<Customer> newCustomerList = mydictionaryList.OfType<Customer>().ToList(); 

        newCustomerList.ForEach(i=>Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", i.Name, i.Surname));
        Console.Read();
    }
}

public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is your Object in the dictionary a customer?  How is the customer composed?  It sounds like you want a LINQ select, but without knowing what you want in your customer, we don't know what it should look like.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are bound to be ways of doing it, but you haven't said anything about what's in a Customer, or what the relationship between the string, the object and the customer is.

Here's an example which *may* be appropriate (assuming you're using .NET 3.5 or higher):

```
var customers = dictionary.Select(pair => new Customer(pair.Key, pair.Value)
                          .ToList();
```

Or maybe you're only interested in the keys, which should be the names of the customers:

```
var customers = dictionary.Keys.Select(x => new Customer(x))
                               .ToList();
```

Or maybe each value is already a `Customer`, but you need to cast:

```
var customers = dictionary.Values.Cast<Customer>().ToList();
```

Or maybe some of your values are `Customer` values but others aren't, and you want to skip those ones:

```
var customers = dictionary.Values.OfType<Customer>().ToList();
```

(You can also use the constructor of `List<T>` which takes an `IEnumerable<T>` but I tend to find the `ToList` extension method more readable.)

---

EDIT: Okay, now we know the requirements, the options are:

```
List<Customer> customers = dictionary.Values.OfType<List<Customer>>()
                                            .First();
```

or

```
List<Customer> customers = dictionary.Values.OfType<List<Customer>>()
                                            .FirstOrDefault();
```

The latter will leave you with `null` if there are no such values; the former will throw an exception.

Comment: I swear he's like a rep black hole.  None can escape his gravitational pull.

Comment: Also, if his TValue may or may not be a Customer (if he's keeping more than one type as the Value) it would be more appropriate to use OfType<Customer> than Cast.

Comment: @Will: Nice catch. Will add that option.

Comment: I have edited my question explaining a bit more and put a test.I cannot seem to get a result out of it.
What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: @devnet247: In your test case, the dictionary already contains the list itself as a value. Do you just want to pick the first list that's present in the dictionary? Or combine lists together?

Comment: yes the dictionary already contains the list. I just want to pick up first list and once i have that list eg "listExtractedFromDictionary" set it to another list
eg List<Customer>customers=listExtractedFromDictionary

I am very very grateful.Hope its clear

Comment: THANKS a lot all works now.Really appreciate your time in explaining with various examples

Answer (score 1):

Given your updated code, the relevant object in your list is a `List<Customer>`, so that's what you should check for with OfType. Try soemthing like this to form a single list from all the lists in your dictionary.

```
var newList = mydictionaryList.Values.OfType<List<Customer>>().SelectMany(list => list).ToList();
```

Otherwise, you could get a list of lists.

Comment: Hi,
It works in my noddy example however in my real one by object is composed of other objects.Bit complicated to post all the code and not sure I can. In a nutshell.If I were todo it conventionally with a foreach how would you do it.It's a pity as it works with exmple posted.mmmmm bit lost now